# Replace Specific Value in Array of Object swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

I need to change values in array of object

Array of selected sports which is received from API

## Update API Response

```
arrSelectedID = [["slug": cricket,
"id": 1,
"banner_image": https://_1558964043.jpg,
"name": Cricket,
"icons": {
    black = "https://sport_icon_cricket_black.png";
    green = "https://sport_icon_cricket_green.png";
    grey = "https://sport_icon_cricket_gray.png";
    white = "https://sport_icon_cricket_white.png";
}],
["slug": soccer,
"banner_image": https://1558964051.jpg
"icons": {
    black = "https://sport_icon_soccer_black.png";
    green = "https://sport_icon_soccer_green.png";
    grey = "https://sport_icon_soccer_gray.png";
    white = "https://sport_icon_soccer_white.png";
},
"id": 2,
"name": Soccer]]
```

My Array

```
struct ObjSportsList:Codable {
    var id:Int
    var name:String
    var slug:String
    var selected:Bool?
    var icons:ObjSportsIcon
}

struct ObjSportsIcon:Codable {
    var green:String
    var grey:String
    var white:String
    var black:String
}

var arrSports:[ObjSportsList] = [] // Array which is custom object
```

> Below response is printed my custom object "ObjSportsList"

```
arrSports = (id: 1,
name: "Cricket",
slug: "cricket",
selected: nil,
), 

(id: 2,
name: "Soccer",
slug: "soccer",
selected: nil,
),

(id: 3,
name: "Baseball",
slug: "baseball",
selected: nil,
),
```

I want to change "selected" values = true which is get id from API array in "data" Example : [1,3] only change 1st and 3rd `selected` values == true

I try to work with below code but array not updated

```
                        for (index, var sports) in self.arrSports.enumerated() {
                            for selectedSports in arrSelectedID {
                                if selectedSports["id"] as! Int == sports.id {
                                    sports.selected = true
                                }
                            }
```

Comment: Not the first time you change the question after people has answered, have some respect for those trying to help and prepare yourself properly so that the question you first ask is the one you want an answer for,

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code to replace the specific value in `Array` of object

```
let aryIDS = [1,3]

for (index, sport) in arrSports.enumerated(){
    if aryIDS.contains(sport.id) {
        arrSports[index].selected = true
    }
}
print(arrSports) //Received updated array
```

Comment: Does not received updated array, And I updated response of API, Please check it and let me know how to fix this

Comment: Obviously, Because earlier you're said that you have an array of Int.

Comment: I try with your array`let aryIDS = [1,3]` as per answer but did not work. API Change recently half an hour ago, but I fix this problem with static array, then I will change dynamic array key and id

Answer (score 0):

I fix the issue with my own code, Please check this code

```
                for (index, sports) in self.arrSports.enumerated() {
                    for selectedSports in arrSelectedID {
                        if selectedSports["id"] as! Int == sports.id {
                            self.arrSports[index].selected = true
                        }
                    }
                }
```